# New website in IIS will not load

Tags: iis

I am hosting two websites on my server and they function fine. These two websites are accessible inside and from the internet. I am trying to add a third local-only website, but it will not load in the browser. I have checked bindings, default document, user that the website runs as, permissions. When I test settings I get two checkmarks. I've even checked DNS. All I see is this page cannot be displayed.

I've compared settings with my other two websites and the only thing that's different is the alias, the fact that it will not use https, and the file path. I don't know what else to check.

System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Comment: Need more information.

Comment: Did you check event viewer for logs about the error?

Comment: No, what event should I be looking for?

Comment: @harrymc: Care to explain what's missing? Bear in mind I will not provide the address to my websites or IP addresses for security reasons.

Comment: Your answer contains exactly the kind of information that without it there are too many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. It was with my DNS settings. I have a CNAME record for the website that was redundant. i.e. `page.domain.local.domain.local`
I have corrected this to read `page.domain.local` and all is working.
I located the problem by running nslookup in debug mode. To do this enter the following in the command line:

```
nslookup
set debug
page.domain.local
```